# Trouble with Google OAuth for Google Ads API - python

Tags: python, web-applications, google-ads-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I am developing a Web App to get information of Google Ad campaigns on behalf of users. I am using the python lib that google provides but I am having a lot of trouble just getting the initial credentials to start testing calls to the API.

I am following this documentation: https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-python/wiki/OAuth-Web-Application-Flow

I already completed Step 1 and I have my client secret, client ID and redirect uri.

In Step 2 I need to setup the OAuth web flow and it says to use the following code:

```
import google.oauth2.credentials
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow

# Initialize the flow using the client ID and secret downloaded earlier.
flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
    'client_secret.json',
    scope=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords'])
# Indicate where the API server will redirect the user after the user completes
# the authorization flow. The redirect URI is required.
flow.redirect_uri = 'https://www.example.com/oauth2callback'
```

When I run my app I get the following error: from_client_secrets_file() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given), so I changed the code to the following:

```
import google.oauth2.credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import Flow

# Initialize the flow using the client ID and secret downloaded earlier.
flow = Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
    'client_secret.json',
    scope=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords'],
    redirect_uri = ['https://www.dintdigital.com'])
```

But I keep getting the same error and I don't understand why because I am literally giving from_client_secrets_file 3 arguments instead of 2, as the error says.

I currently have my own Google Ads account and I am using this to test and build my app, but in the end I want to use the app to connect to any user's account and get their ads info (if they give me permission after authenticating).

I need to get all the credentials and tokens for my account first, but Google's documentation is kind of difficult to understand. Please help !

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show the full Traceback.

Answer (score 0):

The `from_client_secrets_file` class method has the following signature:

```py
from_client_secrets_file(client_secrets_file, scopes, **kwargs)
```

You provide the `client_secrets_file` parameter, but not the `scopes` one. Instead you have a different parameter `scope`, which will be added to the `kwargs` mapping. Change `scope` to `scopes` and the error will go away.

(I also noticed that your redirect URI doesn't look correct. This is where the flow will finish and provide the access token, so it's most likely not your home page. If it actually is, please ignore this comment.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing this steps because you want refresh token and access token . I am suggesting you to get refresh token and access token using below link. I used same and it is very easy and useful.

**NOTE:** In below code you can get any API refresh and access token , you just simply need to change scope.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t0RKgHskYwI&ab_channel=LinuXamination

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34700532)